# How can I change this print() error message into an input() prompt?

Tags: python

How could I change the `print` statement to another input statement that says: "Try again. Your number must be between 1 and 50: " if `num` does not equal 1-50 or is not an integer?

```
while True:
    num = input('Enter a whole number between 1 and 50: ')
    try:
        num = int(num)
        if num<1 or num>50:
            print("Your number must be between 1 and 50, try again.")
            continue
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("You did not enter a number, try again.")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the message after you used it once:

```
message = 'Enter a whole number between 1 and 50: '
while True:
   
    num = input( message )
    try:
        # change the message
        message = "Your number must be between 1 and 50, try again: "

        num = int(num)
        if 1 <= num <= 50:
            break

    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Test:

```
Enter a whole number between 1 and 50: dont want to
Your number must be between 1 and 50, try again: 99
Your number must be between 1 and 50, try again: -2
Your number must be between 1 and 50, try again: 1
```

Comment: @JasonWada This will loop until you input a valid value. You do not get a special error message if you input "Hugo" instead of a number, instead the prompt will repeat.